# Meaning of "the demographics are going to leave us with lots of jobs"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Well, Arthur C. Clarke, a famous science fiction writer from the 1950s, said that, "We overestimate technology in the short term, and we underestimate it in the long term." And I think that's some of the fear that we see about jobs disappearing from artificial intelligence and robots. That we're overestimating the technology in the short term. But I am worried whether we're going to get the technology we need in the long term. **Because the demographics are really going to leave us with lots of jobs that need doin**g and that we, our society, is going to have to be built on the shoulders of steel of robots in the future.

[Why we will rely on robots](https://www.ted.com/talks/rodney_brooks_why_we_will_rely_on_robots/transcript#t-58944)

Hi, I would like to know what does this sentence mean: "Because the demographics are really going to leave us with lots of jobs that need doing".

As far as I understand, I think it means that because of the demographic problem, which is the low birth rate, in the future, we will have too much jobs for the workable population. 
So, we will suffer a lack of labor force. 
Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with your interpretation. It may also refer to the large number of Baby Boomers that will retire in the next few years. They will take a lot of experience when they retire, and there may not be enough experienced Gen Xs or Gen Ys to replace them.